# An alternative valediction for sailors to “fair winds”

Tags: letter-writing, nautical-terms

I'm looking for an alternative to signing emails to sailors instead of "fair winds" or "following seas".

> [***"Fair Winds and Following Seas”***](https://www.battleshipnc.com/fair-winds/) is a gesture of good luck to those we will miss and sailors who have served with honor and courage. The *combination of phrases* implies that a vessel will have good winds, and not have to pound into the waves.

[-Battle Ship North Carolina webpage](https://www.battleshipnc.com/fair-winds/)

Comment: This question will probably be closed due to lack of clarity, "following seas" is pretty meaningless...

Comment: @Lambie Not so. '_Following seas_ are defined by Bowditch’s American Practical Navigator as “A sea in which the waves move in the general direction of the heading” and can be dangerous if the winds and sea are too strong. But the mariners’ traditional blessing implies that both are comfortably rolling in the same direction as the boat.' [[Battleship North Carolina](https://www.battleshipnc.com/fair-winds/)]

Comment: https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/NHC/fairwinds.htm

Comment: 'Bon voyage' seems ELL standard.

Answer (score 3):

> Calm sea and a prosperous voyage

This is a well-known alternative to the phrases cited by the poster, and is the English language title of the [orchestral concert overture op. 27 by Felix Mendelssohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calm_Sea_and_Prosperous_Voyage_(Mendelssohn)) — German title *Meeresstille und glückliche Fahrt*.

It has the advantage that you could attach a link to the music in an email, [apparently free here](https://imslp.org/wiki/Meeresstille_und_gl%C3%BCckliche_Fahrt%2C_Op.27_(Mendelssohn%2C_Felix)), although I prefer to reward artists by buying their products.

Comment: A well-known alternative to what?

Comment: @Lambie — To “fair winds” or “following seas”.

Comment: @Cascabel — I know you mean well by clarifying the question and that it is a noble thing to do, but by being over-specific it does tend to move the goal posts a little. Oh well, just a musical interlude.

Comment: @Cascabel — As I hope my comment implied, I don’t really care, I was just having a little fun in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

***May the wind always be at your back*** (and the sun warm upon
your face)

...is an [Irish blessing for sailor](https://boating.ncf.ca/fun/poetry.html)s.